# Difference between workers and worker_connections in gunicorn?

Tags: python, gunicorn

Reading Gunicorn's docs I see two parameters, worker being the value of WEB_CONCURRENCY and worker_connections being the number of simultaneous clients.

Wouldn't the number of workers be the same as the number of clients it can handle at the same time? [assuming worker class as gevent].

It seems to be pretty clear that I'm wrong in my assumption, could someone please explain what the difference is between them?

Answer (score 7):

`workers` — is a number of OS processes for handling requests. By default it is equal to the value of  `WEB_CONCURRENCY` environment variable, and if it is not defined, the default is 1.
`worker_connections` — is a maximum count of active greenlets grouped in a pool that will be allowed in each process (for "gevent" worker class).

By the way, the [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-workers) recommends:
DO NOT scale the number of workers to the number of clients you expect to have. Gunicorn should only need 4-12 worker processes to handle hundreds or thousands of requests per second.